# Clicking on a editing button in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to click on this specific edit button. I'm using find method in ruby to do so, the problem I'm running into is that It's not able to find the specific element.

```
<i ng-click="grid.appScope.editMOO(row.entity._id)" class="ca ca-pencil-square-o" role="button" tabindex="0"></I>
```

Here is my code trying to click on the edit button.

```
find('.ng-click', class: 'ca ca-pencil-square-o').click
```

Comment: '.ng-click' will look for elements with the class `ng-click`. Its actually an attribute in your code. You could fix it by adding a class to the buttons that you target. But I would add an actual text to the button for screen readers that you can use to target in Capybara. https://accessible360.com/accessible360-blog/use-aria-label-screen-reader-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the desired button you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
find('i[ng-click^="grid.appScope.editM"]').click
```

or

```
find('i[ng-click^=grid.appScope.editM]').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `ng-click` attribute for this is not a great idea, instead do either of

```
find('i[role="button"]', class: 'ca-pencil-square-o').click
```

or

```
find('i[role="button"].ca-pencil-square-o').click
```

Note, if you wanted to test for both classes like you were doing originally you pass an array to the `class` option

```
find('i[role="button"]', class: ['ca', 'ca-pencil-square-o']).click
```

but that doesn't really make sense to check for both 'ca' and 'ca-pencil-square-o'